# Uniqueness of O.D.E

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, lipschitz-functions, implicit-function-theorem

Prove that the o.d.e. $(\frac{3}{2}\sqrt{|y|}+1+x^2)\frac{dy}{dx}+2xy=0$ has unique local solutions with $y(x_0) = y_0$ for any $x_0$ and $y_0$.

Does the existence and uniqueness theorem for o.d.e's apply?

Attempt:

In my book it states that for an exact equation (an o.d.e. of the form $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{-N(x, y)}{M(x,y)}$ where $M = F_y$ and $N = F_x$ for some $C^1$ function $F(x, y)$) the o.d.e. was equivalent to the implicit solution $F(x,y) = c$. So by applying the implicit function theorem, we can assert the local existence of solutions for the implicit equation as long as $M(x, y)$ is not zero. In the specific o.d.e. we have, $M(x,y)$ is never zero so there is always a solution. Is this correct? If so, that's great, but does the existence and uniqueness theorem apply?

Comment: I'm not really understanding your question. Why _wouldn't_ the existence and uniqueness theorem for ODEs apply?

Comment: This question was in a chapter about the Implicit Function Theorem and we covered local uniqueness and existence long ago so I thought it shouldn't apply. But, when I personally reached the conclusion it did I had to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, the implicit function theorem works in this case.

For the existence and uniqueness theorem I will now rewrite the equation as
$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = f(x,y), $$
where 
$$ f(x,y) = \frac{-2xy}{\frac{3}{2}\sqrt{|y|}+1+x^2}. $$
We need to check if $f$ is locally Lipschitz with respect to $y$. However,
$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = -\frac{2x(\frac{3}{4}\sqrt{|y|}+1+x^2)}{(\frac{3}{2}\sqrt{|y|}+1+x^2)^2} $$
is continuous, hence $f\in C^1$ and in particular $f$ is locally Lipschitz and the uniqueness theorem does apply.

Comment: How did you say its locally Lipschtiz? I was also coming to the same conclusion but I was concerned that I was because we have already covered this material long ago and were now going over the implicit function theorem and thought maybe the old material shouldn't apply but I guess it does :)

Comment: actually isn't it globally lipschitz

Comment: nvm i see it is locally lipschitz because $f$ and $f_y$ are both bounded so my MVT in some region R we look at (where R is the rectangle formed by coordinates $(a, b), (a, c), (b, d) a < c, b<d, \text{ where } a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$) there is some M>0 s.t. $f_y$ is always less than M. Then we only have to care about what happens to $f_y$ at infinity (to make sure $f$ is not changing faster and faster as things get big) and the leading powers are both in the denominator of $f_y$ so it goes to 0 as its inputs get arbitrarily large.